# Alias Target in Route 53 | Load Balancer vs EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to link my `SSL` to the domain, I see some people when they add `Alias Target` to domain records they choose `Load Balancer` and some other people choose `EB environment link`

What the different when add SSL whether choose  `Load Balancer` or  `EB environment link` ?

Comment: "Load Balancer or Load Balancer"  can you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry!  updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create Alias record to the EB environment if you use it. It will automatically map to the load balancer if you have load-balanced EB environment.

In contrast you create the record to load balancer when you don't use EB, and you setup your own load balancer for your custom architecture.